# Show $\frac{1}{x}\leq \ln(2x+1)-\ln(2x-1)$ for $x\geq 1$.

Tags: inequality

Prove that for $x\geq 1$ the following inequality is true: $$\dfrac{1}{x}\leq \ln(2x+1)-\ln(2x-1).$$

Can anyone help with this problem? I thought about some hours but any ideas

Comment: do you know some identity implying log(a)-log(b) ?

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET, Yes of course. $\ln(2x+1)-\ln(2x-1)=\ln\dfrac{2x+1}{2x-1}$

Comment: Hint: $\ln x=\int_1^x \frac 1 t\,dt$ and $\frac 1 t$ is convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\ln(2x+1)-\ln(2x-1)-\frac 1x$. Then, we have
$$f'(x)=\frac{2}{2x+1}-\frac{2}{2x-1}+\frac 1{x^2}=\frac{-1}{x^2(2x+1)(2x-1)}\lt 0$$
for $x\ge 1$ with $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$.

Comment: So $f'<0$. We have that $f$ is descreasing. So what is next?

Comment: @RFZ: We have $f(1)\gt 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$. The result follows from these.

Comment: @RFZ  $f$ is decreasing and so $f$ is bounded  below by its limit at infinity

Comment: @Nizar, Thanks a lot! By the way nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, show that if $f(t)$ is a convex differentiable function on $[a,b]$ then $$(b-a)f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \leq \int_{a}^b f(t)\,dt$$

In the above case, $a=2x-1,b=2x+1, f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$.